# how to handle api exception when using eventChannel factory?

Tags: redux-saga

How would one use the eventChannel factory (subscribing to updates from firestore) BUT handle the possible exception that may occur when subscribing to send a "subscribeToUpdatesFailed" back to redux?  https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html

Very similar to http://developingthoughts.co.uk/live-data-with-firebase-and-redux-saga/, how with adding the ability to check for an exception.

So trying to achieve the same sort of result as per the follow non-saga code below.  That is ability to pass back to redux the point of: Request, RequestFailed, or (hopefully) multiple ongoing RequestResponses as they come in.

```
export function requestFirebaseListItems() {
  return function _(dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestedAction());
    firebase.firestore().collection('todos')
      .onSnapshot(
        (querySnapshot) => {
          dispatch(fulfilledAction(querySnapshot.docs));
        },
        (error) => {
          dispatch(rejectedAction);
        },
      );
  };
}
```